# Drawing bidirectional arrows in a latex graph

Tags: tikz-arrows, graphs, commutative-diagrams

I would like to reproduce the figure below in latex:
[image]

I know how to make unidirectional arrows, but I'd like to represent each pair of unidirectional arrows as a single bidirectional arrow. I was wondering if anyone here could give me some hints!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Questions of the form "Please draw this for me", which show no effort on the part of OP, often don't get answered. You will get more help if you post some code showing what you have tried and give a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that).

Answer (score 5):

A very simple attempt with `tikz-cd`, but I don't know how to define a single bidirectional arrow.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=50, column sep=50, arrows={rightharpoondown, shift right=.25ex}]
    A \arrow[r] \arrow[d, "\beta"'] \arrow[dr, "\alpha"' pos=2/5] 
  & C \arrow[l, "\beta"'] \arrow[d] \arrow[dl] \\
    T \arrow[r, "\beta"'] \arrow[u] \arrow[ur] 
  & G \arrow[l] \arrow[u, "\beta"'] \arrow[ul, "\alpha"' pos=2/5]
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

[image]

with pure `tikz`:

```
\documentclass[12pt, tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, positioning, quotes}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[auto=right,
node distance = 32mm and 32mm,
 N/.style = {minimumsize=8mm},
ys/.style = {yshift=#1},
xs/.style = {xshift=#1}
                        ]
\node (a)                   {A};
\node (c)   [right=of a]    {C};
\node (t)   [below=of a]    {T};
\node (g)   [below=of c]    {G};
\draw[-{Straight Barb[right]}]
    ([ys= 1.4pt] c.west)  edge ["$\beta$"]    ([ys= 1.4pt] a.east)
    ([ys=-1.4pt] a.east)  edge                ([ys=-1.4pt] c.west)
    ([ys= 1.4pt] g.west)  edge                ([ys= 1.4pt] t.east)
    ([ys=-1.4pt] t.east)  edge ["$\beta$"]    ([ys=-1.4pt] g.west)
    ;
\draw[-{Straight Barb[left]}]
    ([xs=-1.4pt] t.north)   edge ["$\beta$" ']  ([xs=-1.4pt] a.south)
    ([xs= 1.4pt] a.south)   edge              ([xs= 1.4pt] t.north)
    ([xs= 1.4pt] c.south)   edge ["$\beta$" ']  ([xs= 1.4pt] g.north)
    ([xs=-1.4pt] g.north)   to                ([xs=-1.4pt] c.south)
%
    ([ys=-2pt] g.north west)  edge [pos=0.55,"$\alpha$" ']  ([xs=-2pt] a.south east)
    ([ys= 2pt] a.south east)  edge                          ([xs= 2pt] g.north west)
%
    ([xs=-2pt] t.north east)  edge [pos=0.55,"$\alpha$"]  ([ys= 2pt] c.south west)
    ([xs= 2pt] c.south west)   to                           ([ys=-2pt] t.north east)
        ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```